# Why does a lightsaber turn off when a Jedi dies or drops it?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, lightsaber

I rewatched the three newer movies and noticed that whenever a Jedi was killed, or let go of their lightsaber, it immediately turned off.  What was curious was that the lightsaber turns off right away, when a Jedi is killed, even before it leaves their hand (if it does fall out).  I could understand if the button needs to be held for it to stay on, but when a Jedi is shot and is still holding the lightsaber why would it turn off?

Comment: You beat me to this question :(

Comment: A better question: What's the *point* of lightsabers when all you need are a thousand super mega droids, and a few dozen Death Stars? In a 'infinite universe', anything's possible! ...Other than putting the fate of the galaxy in a bunch of glorified swords.

Comment: @muntoo I was thinking, what if they connected lightsabres to the sides of those spinning wheel-like droids that are in Episode III.  How deadly would that be!

Comment: @muntoo: lightsabers are for when you need precision and a measured response.  Battle Droids are for when you need an army.  The Death Star is for when you decide, "Nuke the site from orbit, it's the only way to be sure."

Comment: @Jeff Nuking from orbit is always an option. Scratch that; THE option. :)

Comment: Wait. Who said that Lightsabers are sentient beings?

Comment: In *Foundation and Earth*, part 4, we learn that most Solarian robots work by drawing the power that their owner's brain generates, and that all these robots stop functioning when their owner dies.  A lightsaber needs a continuous power source, so it probably also takes the power from the owner, and that's why it turns off when the owner dies.

Comment: This is why https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ZMmbYUi_dg

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Most lightsabers have a built-in deadman switch.  It would just be irresponsible for a Jedi to construct such a dangerous weapon without one.  Essentially, if the handle is not being held (has pressure on it) the weapon deactivates.  This prevents a lightsaber from flying away from the disarmed Jedi and scything through his allies (or slashing the viewport of the space station, etc).

When a lightsaber is thrown, the Jedi uses the force to guide it and also keep the switch from closing, deactivating the blade.

Oddly, there's no mention of this in the EU, but it's presence can be clearly seen in the series, as you noted.

Comment: How do you think it functions when a jedi is killed but they cling onto their lightsabre as they fall?  It still turns off right away.

Comment: Upon death, their grip still loosens.  There's probably a minimum pressure required.

Comment: Any source for this explanation?

Comment: In some of the films, a jedi throws an active lightsaber.

Comment: I'm sure I read somewhere that there was a switch lock for throwing and so on - but can't remember the souce. Might even have been an illustrated guide

Comment: @JayBazuzi: I discussed this in the answer: "When a lightsaber is thrown, the Jedi uses the force to guide it and also keep the switch from closing, deactivating the blade."

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ: 1. Your name is **really** hard to type.  2. It's mostly speculation, but there is a discussion in _I, Jedi_ of lightsaber construction and it's partly drawn from there.  This may be what Horus recalls as well.

Comment: Rigor Mortis...?

Comment: @Jeff: weird, I read your answer twice and didn't see that.

Comment: @muntoo: [Rigor Mortis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigor_mortis) doesn't set in for hours after death.

Comment: Good question and good answer, but is there any cannon evidence to this? Cheers.

Comment: I seem to remember Jaina concetrating on keeping her lightsabre turned on as she threw it at something from eith NJO or LoF.

Comment: I just watched ESB last night on bluray, and I noticed something, when Luke fights himself/vader in the cave and chops the head off the body, you clearly see the lightsaber still ignited and still being gripped to vaders body as it fell.

Comment: @Jared: The illusion in the cave is not Vader, but a representation of the evil potential within himself that Luke had to overcome.  This is also the ONLY instance where a lightsaber has failed to exstinguish upon the holder's death - clearly showing us (though Luke didn't notice) that the threat it represented had NOT been defeated.  I thought it was a brilliant bit of foreshadowing for the temptation in Cloud City and RotJ.

Comment: @HorusKol: I'm a bit late to this reply, but I re-read *I, Jedi* recently and Corran Horn does mention building a 'lock' position into his lightsaber's activation switch for throwing.  His lightsaber also has a variable-length blade, so it isn't like it's completely 'standard', but that doesn't seem like an uncommon modification.

Comment: @Jeff And even then, SIth aren't very well known for being considerate to others, so they may skip the dead man's grip feature. Also, being a dream sequence, Luke may not know that there is that kind of feature or just plain does not focus on turning the lightsabre off after chopping the hand.

Comment: Let's not forget that what Luke fights in the cave is not a real physical entity. Perhaps it is entirely a hallucination, in which case the normal characteristics of a lightsabers construction need not apply uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

I was fairly sure that lightsabers worked with/powered with the force? So when a jedi dies, they obviously aren't able to put force power into the saber. It explains why droids and the like can't use them, too. It also explains how they can be thrown (although I don't think they throw an activated saber in IV, V, or VI)

Comment: We-e-elll, Darth Vader throws his lightsabre in VI.  And what about Han Solo or Grevious?  They both use lightsabres, and they don't have any force training.

Comment: Okay, nevermind then!

Comment: @Rob - yes that was how Obi Wan originally described it in ANH.  I got all excited in the theatre when Han used it thinking ohh cool he is going to be a jedi too... alas no.

Comment: Could it not still be that way? Han just has a higher than normal midi-chlorian(sp?) count? He seems to be a pretty good pilot...

Comment: @Rob and he also found Luke on Hoth, which would have been very unlikely without sub-conscious guidance from the force.

Comment: @Sydenam: Luke could have been unconsciously calling for help, and his friends (with whom he is very familiar) would have heard him best.  And since a lightsaber is a simple mechanical tool (albeit INCREDIBLY dangerous), anyone could activate one.

Comment: @Jeff I have already made a comment for both sides of this argument.  The only relation I "know" between the force and lightsabres, is that you need to use the force to construct one.

Comment: I think it is also implied that you need to be in tune with the Force in order to develop the ability to use a lightsaber without doing something dumb like slicing your own head off.

Comment: While the Jedi can channel their force powers through the blade, making stronger strikes and allowing them to sometimes cut things easier than normal, especially hard metals or the like.. a lightsaber is not created by their force powers. Hand being able to activate Lukes blade on Hoth is a prime example. Luke also turned on his fathers saber in the original Star Wars before receiving any force training at all.It's also been answered in the role playing source books that many non jedi throughout the galaxy have carried and used lightsabers for defense. They're powered by a powerful energy cell

Comment: @Rob. Han was led to Luke on Hoth by the spirit of Obi-Wan. that is why after Obi was telling Luke to go to Dagobah to find Yoda and learn from him, Han appeared right from the save vector as the spirit of Obi-Wan. Obi-Wan was also guiding and empowering Luke since he became one with the force. That is why Luke was able to use the force to pull his lightsaber to him when he was hanging upside down in the Wampa ice cave. Obi-wan was telling him how to use the force & giving him extra power.

Comment: @Sydenam, but Grievous does have training. He was trained by Count Dooku. He states this when fighting Obi-Wan.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a possible force-link between user and weapon/tool.  The lightsaber crystal only shows to that specific Jedi, so, when a Jedi is ousted in combat, maybe that bond is broken.

Comment: What source do you have for this 'force-link'?  Also, there's in-universe evidence of people using other combatant's lightsabers (ref: Episode 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) - clearly the weapon isn't tied to a single user.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some kind of bond with the lightsaber crystal,Jedi,and force so when the Jedi dies the Jedi disappears from the bond so the force can't power the lightsaber and it shuts off or in a one of the movies where earth Vader battles obi won you can see a wire so maybe the wire bends a little and the lightsaber turns off.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the same thing happens to non-Force-users...

Answer (score 0):

The Expanded Universe has a few instances where the Jedi specifically locks the lightsaber into the on position and then proceeds to do something else.

Comment: Are there any sources you can find for your answer to provide evidence for you thoughts to strengthen your answer? It would really help round out your answer and attract more attention. Also take a look at our [tour] and get on the way to earning your first [badge!](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges). Further I hope you don't mind the small edits I've made to your answer.