# exactly how do lightsabers turn on/off?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

It seems that when someone drops their saber it turns off, but Lukes hand still gripped his when his hand got chopped. Why did it extinguish?

Comment: Also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85811/how-do-lightsabers-turn-off-and-on?rq=1